# Using mahout in eclipse WITHOUT USING MAVEN

Tags: eclipse, mahout

I really don't want to use maven because it seems like a massive hassle. Is there any way to just download mahout and use it in my eclipse project? All I get from using maven is build path errors and millions of warnings.

I have searched for a way to do this but people seem pretty set on using maven all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not set on it.  I *hate* Maven.

The problem you'll have with Mahout is that they've decided to use it.  If that's the case, you're stuck with it, too.

Comment: I tried downloading mahout and hadoop from apache's mirrors. Those downloads contain all the .jar's with the actual code in them. I then made User Libraries in eclipse and added those libraries to my project in eclipse. The errors in the code are now all gone, but I get this:

13/06/18 17:38:51 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: wrong value class: org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.Kluster is not interface org.apache.mahout.clustering.Cluster

Comment: you've gotta have hadoop installed and running on your machine when you run hahout.  can't speak to that error.  i know i have trouble with the mirror checkouts, too.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't think you could use Mahout without Maven, because Mahout is a Maven project! In eclipse, you could install maven plugin (or in elicpse marketplace, find integrated M2), you could refer this post [Maven in Eclipse: step by step installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620127/maven-step-by-step)

The blog is very good for us to learn how to install mahout: [how to install mahout](http://nivirao.blogspot.com/2012/04/installing-apache-mahout-on-ubuntu.html)

BTW, you could ignore installing hadoop. If Mahout cannot find HADOOP configuration on your computer, it will run locally.

Comment: The reason I've been having such a hard time with maven is that I can't use it with my useraccount. So I always have to use:

sudo mvn install.

The result of this is that maven says BUILD SUCCESSFUL but I can't use any of it in eclipse. When I import it to eclipse it just says "Parent of resource /opt/mahout_trunk/buildtools/target/classes/META-INF/maven/org.apache.mahout/mahout-buildtools/pom.properties is marked as read-only" or it says "/opt/mahout_trunk/buildtools/target/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (Permission denied)" - things like that. 

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I did it. I downloaded mahout and hadoop from apache's mirrors. Those do contain the .jars that contain the mahout and hadoop code. I added those to User Libraries I created in eclipse and added those User Libraries to the Build Path window in eclipse. I was able to import all the classes I needed. After fixing the code in the Mahout In Action book, I was able to run the clustering example.

It DID still complain at me that "WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable". Nothing from maven was imported.

Comment: I think the read only problem must be the privilege issue. You could try "sudo chmod -R 777 YourMahoutHomeFolderPath". If you use m2 plugin, I think this shouldn't be a problem. Because I actually could build and run the examples in Mahout in Action from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use mahout is by using build tool Maven.Its a great tool for project build and management,nevertheless it throws errors for missing artifacts etc,but you will find the solution to overcome it with the help of maven wiki and the error it shows,it shows you the solution after the error details.

You can very well work on mahout without building it.Just download the necessary jars and add it to the BuildPath in eclipse.You can run this as usual Java program.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but let's answer anyway:

I don't know if things have changed, but I used mahout today for the first time - and I did not use Maven. I simpy followed the steps given in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yD40rVKUwPI

In particular, have a look at the description of the next tutorial: "Note: this tutorial uses maven for the project, unlike the first tutorial." ==> I guess that means that using Maven is not a **must**.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same issue. If you just want to use mahout as a java library for your project, you can use it in eclipse without using maven. You just need to create a user library and upload the jar files into it. Then just put that library into your build path.